# GQL Query Select Kind with name default

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gql

I have firestore data structure like this:

[image: my firestore data structure]

How to achieve to get **ts_app_theme** with name **default** only?

I already try query like this

```
SELECT * FROM ts_app_theme WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR KEY(ts_app_config, '$merchant_key') AND __key__ = KEY(ts_app_theme, 'default')
```

it didn't work..

I can do this

```
SELECT * FROM ts_app_theme WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR KEY(ts_app_config, '$merchant_key')
```

but will return another document in **ts_app_theme** if I have more document other than **default** later..

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GQL is for Firestore in Datastore mode. You can find it in Google docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/gqlreference). Datastore data model has `kind` which that might be compared to SQL table and `entity` which can be compared to SQL row. Due to this structure it's possible to use SQL like querying.

While Firestore in general, like on your screenshot, is NoSQL database. As of it concept it does not contain schema which is could be use in building SQL queries. BTW I wonder where you run those queries, possible there is some nice tool I don't know of.

Regarding querying Firestore I found nice tutorial series starting with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G04w_k3TPTs).

Comment: Hi, I use https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client google api php client for PHP with version of  > 5.4.
I am maintaining old CMS code and need integrate to firestore. I already figure out to use it for create, update, delete, get in firestore, but advanced filter / query is needed to satisfy new features. I use same google docs that you provide in this answer and it didn't help me for this case. I will watch the tutorial.

Comment: Can I ask what kind of database your CMS was using before?

Comment: Still using mysql, firebase only for integration for some features in mobile app..

Comment: I do not use PHP, but this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/tree/master/Firestore seems to be proper API. Good Luck!

Comment: I want to use that library, but unfortunately our cloud environment not supported grpc yet. I will talk to the devOps about this later.